# Nested dict with list unexpectedly updates all when appending to one value

Tags: python

My code of creating a nested dict from 'keys' and then updating one of the elements:

```
keys = ["a", "b", "c"]

d = dict.fromkeys(keys, {'foo':0, 'bar':[]})

d["a"]["bar"].append("x")

print(d)
```

I would expect that the resulting dict be the following (only updating 'bar' under key 'a'):

```
{
  "a": {
    "foo": 0,
    "bar": ["x"]
  },
  "b": {
    "foo": 0,
    "bar": []
  },
  "c": {
    "foo": 0,
    "bar": []
  }
}
```

But instead I'm getting

```
{
  "a": {
    "foo": 0,
    "bar": ["x"]
  },
  "b": {
    "foo": 0,
    "bar": ["x"]
  },
  "c": {
    "foo": 0,
    "bar": ["x"]
  }
}
```

Comment: `dict.fromkeys()` is generally useless with a mutable value, because that value will be shared by every key in the dict.

Comment: The empty list object in each "bar" must be pointing to the same memory address. This issue crops up when supplying mutable values like lists as function arguments. A dict-comprehension will work better here, as @funnydman shows in their answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your approach, you'll get the same objects for every key. Try this instead:

```
keys = ["a", "b", "c"]


result = {k: {'foo': 0, 'bar': []} for k in keys}
result['a']['bar'].append('x')
print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'foo': 0, 'bar': ['x']}, 'b': {'foo': 0, 'bar': []}, 'c': {'foo': 0, 'bar': []}}
```